# What can I do in a Closure in gradle? (How to read the docs)

Tags: gradle

I am currently trying to figure out how to copy a few files and I do not want to make a task for each single file, so I am going through the docs trying to figure out how to use the Copy task.

I am reading this: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:from(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)

How to know what one can do inside **Closure** in the context of **from** method? There is an example on top of the page but I did not manage to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate of the closure will be an instance of CopySpec.

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html

Comment: What is "delegate of closure" ?

Comment: read this: http://dublintech.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/groovy-closures-this-owner-delegate.html